# Amazon Cognito Error : Unable to resolve host cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Trying to get a file hosted on s3 using Cognito (in a Android App) as follows:

```
....
         AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(getCredentials(MyActivity.this));
         S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("mybucket", "myfile"));
....

public static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider  getCredentials(Context ctx)
    {
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                ctx,
                "us-east-1:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx", /* Identity Pool ID */
                Regions.US_EAST_1 /* Region */
            );
        return cognitoProvider;
    }
```

This Error is shown:

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
: I/AmazonHttpClient(3427): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
: I/AmazonHttpClient(3427):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:400)
: I/AmazonHttpClient(3427):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have forgotten to include the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please see [Set Up the SDK for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

This error can also happen if the phone internet data is not switched on. Always check if the device internet or data service is enabled / available before making request to cloud services.

Comment: how to prevent this crash, like if there is no internet at least should show message the no connection or something?